# How to prove that if matrix is singular, then its columns are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that if matrix is singular, then its columns are linearly dependent? I've seen this statement on the internet, but don't know how to prove this without using rank of matrix. I'm more interested in proving "If matrix is singular, then its columns are linearly dependent". I couldn't find any proof without using linear operators.

Comment: ...and how'd you prove this *using* rank of matrix...?

Comment: What is your definition of singular matrix? In the usual definition, a matrix $A$ is called singular if $Ax=0$ for some nonzero vector $x$. It follows immediately from this definition that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, because their linear combination with coefficients taken from $x$ is zero.

Comment: @user1551 i meant matrix with zero-determinant, sorry...

Comment: @DonAntonio i can't use this too...

Comment: Well, then you can try: if a (square, of course) matrix  $\;A\;$ is singular then the homogeneous linear system $\;A\vec x=\vec 0\;$ does *not* have a unique solution, which means that if we reduce the matrix by columns (or by rows, it's the same) there will be at least one column (row) that becomes all zeros, which means this column (row) is linearly dependent in all the other (columns or rows). Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Determinants have two properties that are relevant here which are that exchanging columns changes the sign and multiplying a column by a scalar multiplies the determinant by the scalar.

Now saying that one column is a multiple of another is another way of saying that they're linearly dependent. Call our matrix $A$ and and multiply one linearly dependent column so that it's identical to the other. This gives us a determinant equal to $\alpha \det A$ for some non-zero scalar $\alpha$ and this matrix has two identical columns.

The identical columns can be switched leaving the matrix invariant which means that $\alpha \det A = -\alpha \det A$. This implies that $2\alpha \det A = 0$ and so $\det A = 0$. Therefore the matrix is singular.

Comment: Thank you, but what about $detA = 0$ => columns of matrix are linearly dependent?

Comment: @ЛераЧисковская Same argument backwards. Once you have $\alpha \det A = -\alpha \det A$ you've implied identical columns.

Comment: Can you please explain this?